# Ionic 3 vertical scroll stops working on ion-content when navigating back from map page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I've got a blank starter Ionic 3 app that I'm testing on iOS 131.1.2.

- The homepage has a vertical `<ion-list>` in the `<ion-content>` and scroll works fine on load.
- From the homepage, I've got a nav `push()` to a map page. On the map page, the map works fine. It's a standard Google Maps implementation with a `<div id="map"></div>` in the template to display a Google Map.
- When using the back button to return from the map page to the homepage, vertical scroll stops working on my `<ion-list>`. The app doesn't freeze completely as I can still tap list items to see details etc. It's just the scroll that breaks on going back to the homepage.

What could I try to fix this?

I'm happy to add full reproducible code - I'm just hoping someone might point me in the right direction before having to add all that here. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Mark Reiner, Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: No sorry. I gave up and nobody could help. Good luck